# How to get array value inside a list

Tags: java

How do I get an array value inside a list? I have a prioirty queue and I converted into a list but I am having trouble getting the array values inside the list.

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = ...
 pq.addAll(Arrays.asList(productRatings));
 List l = new ArrayList(pq);
 for(int i =0 ;i<l.size(); i++){
     System.out.println(l.get(i)[0]);
 }
```

I  get an error :
`error: array required, but Object found System.out.println(l.get(i)[0]);`

Comment: Cast it to a variable:`int[] p =  (int[]) l.get(i);` Now print `System.out.println(p[0]); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Either use generics or cast

Your third line lacks angle brackets, `<` and `>`. So you are not using [generics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) there. Your `List` and `ArrayList` are holding objects of type [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html). So, retrieved elements are of type `Object`.

You need to [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) the retrieved objects to their concrete type. Or revise your code to use generics.